# how to upload files to server using backbone + spring rest webservices?

Tags: backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, backbone-views, spring-restcontroller

i am using backbone for views,bootstrap and back end as spring rest web services.
I want to upload a file from from backbone view to server using spring rest webservices.
Any references??

Comment: see this [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-backbone/). i hope meet your answer

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers are capable of uploading files via AJAX while older browsers are not.
If you need to support IE < 10 you will probably need to implement a form+iframe based solution.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2320097/330092
- http://caniuse.com/#search=FormData

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);

$.ajax({
  url: '/rest/endpoint',
  type: 'POST',
  enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
  processData: false, // tell jQuery not to process the data
  contentType: false, // tell jQuery not to set contentType
  data: formData,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: I have no idea of posting multi part data from backbone view to rest web service.when looking for a solution..i am finding backbone with rails examples mostly.please suggest some examples. of using backbone with spring rest,Thank you @u.k

Comment: I would use jQuery to do that. backbone doesn't have a specific implementation for file uploading

Comment: ok i will try by implementing it through jquery,Thank you  @u.k